# In Visual Studio 2013 with Web Essentials, is there a way to revert images encoded with "Encode Image in base 64" to the file name?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

After encoding images to base 64 in the html it is difficult for colleagues to know what image the base 64 code refers to.
Is there a way to revert to the file path for easy updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, doesn't exist a native way to accomplish this task, but you can easily built your own by
database mapping to resource setting, ect...

Comment: well, not the answer I'd hoped for, but it does seem to be THE answer.